# Regarding glitch in rotation of image in 3D by GSAP

Tags: javascript, html, animation, css-animations, gsap

Through this message I just want little help in my piece of code, I am facing a lagging problem while rotating an image in 3D.

https://codepen.io/saar_thack/pen/bGYavRR

This is a Codepen link to review my code.

```
tl.from('.img1',{
y:800,
transformOrigin:'50% 50%, -10',
rotationY:360,
duration:3,
ease:'back',
autoAlpha:0,
```

})

I'll be grateful if you help me to solve this problem.